How to convert image to line art - flutter
I have an app which let users draw image with camera by showing image on CameraPreview widget with less opacity so user can trace the image anywhere.
When user select an image from gallery I want to let them create it into line art where only line or strokes of the image is visible and the background of the image is transparent. Something like this.

I have tried to find how to do this and I found ImageFilter widget which did not help.
Please help me, Thank you.

This is not something that can just be trivially done I think. Maybe there exist third party packages that could but asking for third party solutions is out of the scope for this website

Try this code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


class TransparentImage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TransparentImageState createState() => _TransparentImageState();
}

class _TransparentImageState extends State<TransparentImage> {
  Uint8List? Converted_Image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(color: Colors.black,
        child:Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Converted_Image == null
            ? CircularProgressIndicator()
              : Image.memory(Converted_Image!)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ConvertImage();
  }

  Future<void> ConvertImage() async {
    final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/test.png');
    final List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();

    img.Image originalImage = img.decodeImage(Uint8List.fromList(bytes))!;

    img.Image grayscaleImage = img.grayscale(originalImage);

    img.Image edgeDetectedImage = img.sobel(grayscaleImage);

    img.Image invertedImage = img.invert(edgeDetectedImage);

    Uint8List sketchBytes = Uint8List.fromList(img.encodeJpg(invertedImage));

    setState(() {
      Converted_Image = sketchBytes;
    });
  }
}


Your code generate image with black background and white lines or strokes. `img.Image invertedImage = img.invert(edgeDetectedImage);'added this line to fix it but is there a way to make the background transparent. Thank you
